# Python error: I am unable to install amara using pip

Tags: python, pip, amara

```
(PWPYTHON)ubuntu@ip-10-224-6-63:~$ pip install amara
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): amara in ./PWPYTHON/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
Downloading/unpacking 4Suite-XML>=1.0.2 (from amara)   Downloading 4Suite-XML-1.0.2.zip (2.2MB): 2.2MB downloaded   Running setup.py egg_info for package 4Suite-XML

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from amara) Installing collected packages: 4Suite-XML   Running setup.py install for 4Suite-XML
    Usage:
      -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
      -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
      -c cmd --help
      -c --help-commands
      -c --help-packages

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    Complete output from command /home/ubuntu/PWPYTHON/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/ubuntu/PWPYTHON/build/4Suite-XML/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-l4m_hM-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/ubuntu/PWPYTHON/include/site/python2.7:
    Usage:

  -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

  -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

  -c cmd --help

  -c --help-commands

  -c --help-packages



error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /home/ubuntu/PWPYTHON/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/ubuntu/PWPYTHON/build/4Suite-XML/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-l4m_hM-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/ubuntu/PWPYTHON/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/ubuntu/PWPYTHON/build/4Suite-XML Storing complete log in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

Python v2.7.3

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind

Comment: If i install latest version of amara by specifying the version, this problem won't come up. Apparently, due to urgency i moved on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install it with a specific version or use the below method.

I've tried this solution with other packages. You can use this command to install it. 
`pip install --egg amara`

It should work for amara also.

I'm using it in python 2.7

```
ThinkPad-T430:~$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```