# How to install mysql-connector for python 3.5.1?

Tags: python, mysql, pip, version, connector

I'm on python 3.5.1 and I am having trouble installing mysql connector:

```
install --allow-external mysql-connector-python-rf mysql-connector-python-rf
```

is not working, neither is the normal pip command for mysql-connector-python-rf. I am getting the following message:

```
error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably, this could solve the issue: [What does “error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized” indicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind)

Comment: I used the --egg solution in that post and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `mysql-connector` for `python 3.5.1` up till now, but you can use pymysql to connect mysql to python 3.5.1!

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=port_no, user='db_user', passwd='password', db='db_name')
```