# Error while trying to import python modules

Tags: python, module, installation, pip

I am having difficulty importing and using any python module with Python 2. I am able to import and use numpy and scipy in my code with no problem, but anything downloaded or available on the Internet, I cannot manage to use. I am currently trying to use "rebound" for example: http://rebound.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I typed `pip install rebound` into my Mac Terminal. It tries to download it, saying

> Downloading rebound

then

> Running setup.py install for rebound ... error

and a bunch of file paths and then:

> error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to properly import these modules?

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind  Are you using an old version of pip?  Try typing `pip --version` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using virtualenv? If not, you'll need to sudo pip install.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try prepending `sudo` to your `pip install rebound`

```
sudo pip install rebound
```