# Can I use Numba on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, llvm, numba, llvm-gcc

Numa [requires](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numba) llvmlite, which [only works with](http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/intro/index.html#llvm-compatibility) LLVM up to version 3.7.1. But my version of LLVM, according to `llvm-gcc -v` is

> Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)

Is this version incompatible with llvmlite? Is Apple's versioning different from the scheme the llvmlite docs are referring to? Are LLVM and LLVM-GCC numbered differently? If so how do I find what version of LLVM (as llvmlite is referring to) I have?

How can I use llvmlite, and thus Numba, on OS X (without Conda)?

Comment: Yes, the versioning is different. They used to print the LLVM version it was based on, but it looks like they stopped doing that with 7.0. See https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603027/apple-clang-version

Comment: Anyway if it were me I'd just build llvm myself.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: So for example just `brew llvm` should get be LLVM and then follow the instructions for llvmlite? That works (or at least runs without errors); but I still [get errors installing Numba](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36385785/656912) at that point.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think the best is to install a standalone LLVM through brew. Because XCode always upgrades and Apple LLVM will eventually give up `LLVM 3.7.*` (Maybe they already did, because `3.8` came out `2016/03/18`)

Then, I found this source code of the outdated version Apple LLVM 7.0, which is available via [this link](http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html). Also from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603027/apple-clang-version), you can find out that Apple LLVM 7.0 uses `3.7.0svn` of LLVM.

I think I can translate your question into **"What version of LLVm is Apple LLVM version 7.3.0(clang-703.0.29) based on?"**

Apple LLVM 7.0 is based on `3.7.0` since `2015/04/21`.

Apple skipped 7.1 and 7.2 and went straight to LLVM 7.3.

This is [the release notes of llvm 3.7.1](http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) on `2015/01/05`. and `3.8.0` on `2016/03/18`, before the date Apple LLVM 7.0 is released.

Therefore, Apple LLVM 7.3, being a later version, is highly likely using LLVM beyond `3.7.1`, even `3.8`, so you know. But the source code is not available on their opensource website yet. We can't tell exactly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've now done `brew install llvm` and set up llvmlite (which may not have been necessary?); but I still get an [error when installing Numba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385785/error-installing-numba-on-os-x) (actually when that builds — again? — llvmlite).