# pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3 fails

Tags: python, mysql, pip

```
(ENV)$ pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3
Collecting mysql-connector==2.1.3
  Using cached mysql-connector-2.1.3.zip
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector
  Running setup.py install for mysql-connector
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help
    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    Complete output from command /<DIR>/ENV/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ImtJft/mysql-connector/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FN9lfq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /<DIR>/ENV/include/site/python2.7:
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

       or: -c --help-commands

       or: -c cmd --help



    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/<DIR>/ENV/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ImtJft/mysql-connector/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FN9lfq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /<DIR>/ENV/include/site/python2.7" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ImtJft/mysql-connector
```

This is the error. I have been trying to figure out the error. I did some searching around, but of no use. I am running Fedora 22. I checked to see if it could be if MySQL isn't installed. But `mysql-devel` and `mysql-libs` are installed. Please help.

EDIT: I tried:

```
easy_install mysql-connector==2.1.3
```

And it works. But why is `pip` failing?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Running into the exact same error here.

Comment: Use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python, For my particular need I sticked with using easy_install

Answer (score 2):

Your setuptools version might be outdated.
try upgrading pip:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

You can find information about this error in this thread:

[What does "error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized" indicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind)

Comment: This updated `setuptools 12.0.5 ` to `setuptools-24.3.0`. But the error still persists. I also updated the question.

Comment: @0aslam0 if pip is still failing but easy_install works, you might want  to also upgrade pip: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

I see this as old question, but the error seems to repeat at each mysql-connector upgrade, i download the sources from:

https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.tar.gz

unzip and enter into the folder and apply:

`sudo python setup.py install`

IMHO i think that the problem, at least in my case that use macOS, was the Xcode recently installed.