# Why is pip install mysql-connector fail?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connect

I'm just trying to simply install `python-myconnector` using the very simple instructions provided [**here**](https://github.com/sanpingz/mysql-connector).

But it is failing. Here is the error I get:

````
(my_virtual_env) [my.username@my_machine ~]$ pip install mysql-connector
...
Command "/home/my.username/my_virtual_env/bin/python2.7 -u -c 
  "import setuptools, tokenize;
  __file__='/tmp/pip-build-rLJbLN/mysql-connector/setup.py';
  f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
  code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();
  exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install 
  --record /tmp/pip-mFh5Pg-record/install-record.txt 
  --single-version-externally-managed 
  --compile 
  --install-headers 
  /home/me/my_virtual_env/include/site/python2.7/mysql-connector" 
  failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rLJbLN/mysql-connector/```
````

The full error log can be found [**here**](https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/9919f678eee114cde218bb353091a846) if you need to see it (but I doubt you will)

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?? Also, FYI, I don't have sudo access on this machine. So that's why I am installing it into a virtual environment..

FYI, it seems like it was supposed write something into `/tmp/pip-build-rLJbLN/` but didn't and then it blows up later on when it tries to read from what it was supposed to have written there earlier. So how do I fix this bug??

I have read other solutions to other similar problem [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524946/pip-install-mysql-connector-2-1-3-fails). But I couldn't get any of them to work for me.

Comment: Do you have protobuf installed?

Comment: No. I don't. Do I need to? Why?

Comment: Because it is a requirement, stated by the author: **mysql-connector (version >= 2.2.3) requires Protobuf C++ (version >= 2.6.0)**. This is also written in line 165 of your full error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **mysql-connector** clearly states that it requires `protobuf`

> mysql-connector (version >= 2.2.3) requires Protobuf C++ (version >= 2.6.0)

Just as I commented, your error log insists the same:

> Line 81, 165: Unable to find Protobuf include directory.

Based on your platform, follow this [protobuf C++ installaion instruction](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md), and export the protobuf path so that `pip` can refer that path