# Can't install scrapy with Python 3?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python 3.6.3 and Pip 9.0.1 but still can't install scrapy? I am doing this on windows. When executing the following command

`pip3 install scrapy`

I am greeted with this error first..

```
----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for Twisted
Running setup.py clean for Twisted
Failed to build Twisted
Installing collected packages: Twisted, scrapy
Running setup.py install for Twisted ... error
```

Then it continues, the second error stops it completly and seems a lot more fatal...

```
Command "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-zxkenzjd\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tr72roue-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zxkenzjd\Twisted\
```

I have tried executing the following commands as suggested on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15258644/7318581):

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel
```

Comment: Did you use `pip3 install -U setuptools wheel` or simply `pip`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but trying with `pip3` now results in 'Requirement already up-to-date' so I'm pretty sure its all up to date.

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure. I don't have windows. I'm not able to recreate using 3.6.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: error shows it has problem with module `Twisted`. Maybe try to install `Twisted` with `pip`. You can also see for precompiled module on [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Or use Anaconda distribution - it has `scrapy` on [its packages list](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_win-64) so it could work correctly with Anaconda

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem too but I solved it as follow:

Open the Anaconda Prompt as administrator (For `Windows10`: open `cortana`/search `Anaconda Prompt`/choose `Run as Administrator`)

You should go to the path of Anaconda, for me was like:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd ..
C:\WINDOWS>cd..
C:\>cd  ProgramData
C:\ProgramData>cd Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData>Anaconda3>
```

Then you should run the following command

```
C:\ProgramData>Anaconda3>conda install -c anaconda twisted
```

At some point it asks

```
Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

type `y`. Now `twisted` is installed.

To install `scrapy`, you either install it in Anaconda Prompt (as administrator) by running the following command:

```
C:\ProgramData>Anaconda3>conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

(again `y` for `Proceed ([y]/n)?)`

or on `jupyter notebook` and run the command

```
!pip install scrapy
```

Comment: Just want to point out that Anaconda is not essential to the solution. Simply installing the compiled Twisted whl file as @Bishwas describes can solve this without needing Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

for my env: `Win11 x64` + `Python 3.11 x64`

Solution:

- downloaded related whl

  - [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)

    - Click: `twisted_iocpsupport‑1.0.2‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl`

      - note

        - `cp311` = `CPython 3.11`
        - `amd64` = `x64`
      - download: https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/twisted_iocpsupport-1.0.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
- install whl

  - `pip install twisted_iocpsupport-1.0.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl`