# Python 3.7 Pillow installation issue - Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to install **pillow** on **python 3.7** using command **pip3 install pillow**. The package downloaded **fine** but during installation I got below error. I tried to download using wheel too but it failed too. Any advice? Thanks.

```
Command "c:\...\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\...\\A~1.M\\AppData\
\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-phpvx_2j\\pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,
 __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\...\pip-lde0t8n9-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...\pip-build-phpvx_2j\pillow\
```

Comment: try setuptools and wheel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind

Comment: setuptools already up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be **no support** for **Pillow** for **Python 3.7**. I installed **python 3.6** and then installed pillow successfully.

**pip3 install pillow**

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, I installed Pillow on Python 3.7 all right. This is what I did:

**Install Python 3.7 64 bit**

In the command prompt in Windows, I ran:

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **Python 3.7** in windows and I tried

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

It didn't work, then I tried

```
pip install pillow
```

which didn't work either.
so what I did is I tried

```
pip install Pillow==6.2.1
```

it worked, then I keep installing till the latest version that's

```
pip install Pillow==7.1.1
```

And now I have the latest version which is working fine.

Comment: Yep, the package name is "Pillow" (capital P; which is non-standard, really), so if you do "pip install Pillow" you should get the latest version, whichever it is.

Answer (score 1):

This also means that ReportLab can neighter be installed in Python 3.7 since there is a direct dependency to pillow in there. I use reportlab to generate pdf files. I sincerely hope this will be resolved soon.

Answer (score -1):

I think I will be able to answer this.
My system info are follows:

- Windows 10
- Django version 3.2
- Python version 3.7

I found on the Pillow documentation that the tested for Pillow version is 7.1.0
You can read [here.](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#other-platforms)
for this, you need to launch cmd or anaconda prompt and type

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==7.1.0
```