# How to fix "error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized"

Tags: python, pip, windows-7

I'll note up front that I've seen the [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind), and I've tried installing everything recommended: setuptools, wheel, egg, but I'm still getting the same error.

I'm running into the error while trying to install Picard:

```
C:\>pip install picard
Collecting picard
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/ec/e76d4a84d37e6bd93789bf8f7a15f9e63f94cbc8b79607a2152b3fcc313f/picard-2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from picard) (5.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from picard) (1.42.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<13,>=4.19.14 in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from PyQt5->picard) (4.19.17)
Building wheels for collected packages: picard
  Building wheel for picard (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u-c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bdb484\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lc47_c7l\\picard\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\bdb484\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7ktnx238' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  generating scripts/picard from scripts/picard.in
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'installer/picard-setup.nsi.in'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for picard
  Running setup.py clean for picard
Failed to build picard
Installing collected packages: picard
  Running setup.py install for picard ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bdb484\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lc47_c7l\\picard\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bdb484\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wwek3m3r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bdb484\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lc47_c7l\\picard\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bdb484\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wwek3m3r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\bdb484\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lc47_c7l\picard\
```

I've been googling around for a while without luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the windows-specific part of `setup.py` at https://github.com/metabrainz/picard/blob/d141f019c2b88ab6a3a21c04110dad0522e36616/setup.py#L225-L236, in particular

> generate_file('installer/picard-setup.nsi.in', 'installer/picard-setup.nsi', args)

tries to generate `installer/picard-setup.nsi` from `installer/picard-setup.nsi.in`. However, the source tarball on PyPI doesn't even include the `installer` directory:

```
↪ tar tf picard-2.1.tar.gz | grep installer
↪
```

We've worked on the source distributions a bit last year (https://tickets.metabrainz.org/browse/PICARD-1373), but so far have only tested them on Linux.

If you want to use Picard on Windows, use the installer from https://picard.musicbrainz.org/downloads/.

Comment: Thanks. I know that installer sets up the GUI; will I be able to run Picard from the command line, as well?

Answer (score 1):

> error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'installer/picard-setup.nsi.in'

This is a bug in the `setup.py`: it [tries to generate a file](https://github.com/metabrainz/picard/blob/4b116ac20a3ce7ba57dfad939c94070aec2aa14e/setup.py#L230) without creating the directory `installer` first. Please report the bug to the authors. Try to install from the repository:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/metabrainz/picard.git#egg=picard
```

> error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

This is an option for `python setup.py install`. Try to run `python setup.py install --help` with any `setup.py` and see if it has

```
--single-version-externally-managed  used by system package builders to
                                     create 'flat' eggs
```

near the end.

Comment: Regrettably, I am basically incompetent working in the command line. But I tried installing from the repository and got quite a bit of red text thrown back, the relevant portions -- as best as I can tell -- being "Failed building wheel for picard" and "option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized."

Comment: The repository also seems to be buggy. I tried to clone and install it and `setup.py` failed with *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'*. The authors perhaps never installed their own code on a clean system.

Comment: Regarding the last comment: PyQt5 is a requirement which needs to be installed. See requirements.txt

Comment: @phw `pip install` doesn't look into `requirements.txt`. For it to install dependencies those dependencies must be in `setup.py` in `install_requires`. To avoid maintaining two lists of dependencies people usually read `requirements.txt` in `setup.py`.

Comment: @phd It's also defined in `install_requires`. But I saw that the main issue is that we, by accident, introduced a indirect requirement of `setup.py` on `PyQt5`. So we are going to fix that.