# can't install lens library in python

Tags: python, jupyter

I ve searched and applied solutions from questions with similar error msgs.
The !pip install lens gives me the error:

```
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with 
"Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
            ----------------------------------------
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit 
status 1: 'c:\python3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
    '"'"'C:\\Users\\erjan222\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_qkcxb7t\\accumulation-tree\\setup.py'"'"'; 

__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\erjan222\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_qkcxb7t\\accumulation-tree\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 

    '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\erjan222\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-874bit1_\install-record.txt' 

--single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have searched and applied answer from [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind) and applied its solutions:

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel
```

- !pip install lens --egg, , but pip does not know --egg
- upgraded pip, it's already fresh
- pip install --upgrade setuptools, but setuptools is updated

I did install visual tools installer, but did not select any packages to install,because they all seem diff from what i need.

how can i install this library lens?

Comment: Have you done / tried what's in the first line of error i.e install  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 ?

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek, tha'ts the problem, the installer has many version of them - 2015 to 2019. dont know what distro or package to even install

Comment: This is why I exclusively use an [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) of python...precompiled binaries.  `lens` will still need to be installed with `pip`, but all the dependencies are in `conda`, so you won't get that error.

Comment: I’ll second the use of conda as per @TrentonMcKinney. I absolutely _hate_ dealing with package management, dev environment setup, etc. (as, I imagine, most people do), and it’s been great so far.

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44951456/11301900

Answer (score 0):

apparently it worked! I installed the 14.00 c++ version then installed some packages.

It's the 14.00 c++ visual build tools that **probably** worked.