# --single-version-externally-managed not recognized despite setuptools and wheel up to date

Tags: python, pip, installation, python-wheel, python.net

When entering briefcase dev mode (Beeware) I need to install pythonnet but it keeps failing and giving `--single-version-externally-managed not recognized`...

[An old question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296531/what-does-error-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-ind) suggested using `--egg` or `distribute` noting that `--egg` has now depreciated and `distribute` merged with `setuptools`... so installed the latest versions of `setuptools` and `wheel` but still getting the same error!

```
Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
...
Complete output (6 lines):
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

Setuptools, wheel and python running fully up to date, on Windows 10 and pip 20.1.1.

Hope somebody can help!! :-)